# How do I write Itô's with the special symbol?

Tags: symbols, accents

I am writing my thesis on latex but I do not know how to write Itô's in latex with the symbol on the 'o' . Could someone tell me how can I do it? Do I need a special package?

Comment: ito, what do you mean???

Comment: You mean the ô as in Itô?

Comment: yes thats exactly what I mean. How did you do it?

Comment: how could anyone guess that's what you meant from the question? there are thousands of uses of ô  and  Itô (or ito) isn't a word anyone reading in english is likely to recognise!!! you can use `\^{o}` or simply type  ô if you have specified `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my bad, I thought it was quite obvious. I will be careful next time

Comment: it's completely unclear to me how hooy managed to answer even now.  I have no idea what ito or  Itô mean so there was no hint in the question that you needed  ô  it could have been º or ó or anything that you were looking for:-)

Comment: Just so you know, that symbol is usually called a **circumflex**. At least, it is when it's used in words, names, etc. Mathematicians may simply call it a **hat** or a **roof**, when it is used as part of a mathematical symbol, such as the unit vector *î*

Comment: @DavidCarlisle probably a Thesis in mathematical finance or at least stochastic processes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I totally understand. It\^{o} is a very famous guy and is known to everybody in my circle so I was careless. My apologies, I should have been more precise. I won't make the same mistake again.

Comment: no harm done, actually I have been to lectures on Itô's work (but clearly didn't have a lasting impression on me:-)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Assuming that this is a reference to the late mathematician [Kiyosi Itô](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiyosi_It%C3%B4), it seems he wrote his name in an unusual way.  Wikipedia suggests that although standard romanization would call for a macron, the man himself specifically preferred it to be written with a circumflex, in accordance with a different romanization system.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see. Well, in any case it's a duplicate (cf. my previous comment).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, something like `dB^2=dt`, in some way you get a square root of infinitesimal time increment. Now called stochastic differential equations. Useful to get a high paid job at running Monte Carlo simulations and for programming micro-second trading (or is it nanosecond now ?), with the result of making the people/institutions who have the (now numeric) info and the (soon numeric) money richer every day.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make the ô character with `\^{o}`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
It\^{o}
\end{document}
```

Or you can load `inputenc` package with `utf8` option and give the character as a unicode character:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Itô
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It depends who's transliterating. To quote wikipedia "Although the standard Hepburn romanization of his name is Itō, he used the spelling Itô (Kunrei-shiki romanization). The alternative spellings Itoh and Ito are also sometimes seen in the West." Which just about says it all. The spelling is really up to the individual, in the way that some Russians prefer traditional -ff to modern -v, e.g. Poliakoff/Polyakov. But yeah across languages macrons are more common for long vowels now, but the circumflex was often used for long vowels in the past, e.g. Sanskrit Kâlidâsa, now Kālidāsa

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I just used the same spelling as [Kyoto University's page about Kiyosi Itô](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kenkyubu/past-director/ito/ito-kiyosi.html).